# Showing multiple overlays in single geo point..?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an image to show in the overlay while clicking in the drop pin in the map. Possibly,Two or more images belongs to the same latitude and longitude. In this case, I want to show all the images belongs to that particular latitude and longitude..! How can i achieve this.?

This is what i have tried..!

```
   for (int i = 0; i < AllData.neardeallist.size(); i++) {
        mapOverlays = mapview.getOverlays();

        drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);
        itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem>(
                drawable, mapview);

        point = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(AllData.neardeallist
                .get(i).getLatitude()) * 1E6),
                (int) (Double.parseDouble(AllData.neardeallist
                        .get(i).getLongitude()) * 1E6));
        CustomOverlayItem overlayItem = new CustomOverlayItem(point,
                StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(StringEscapeUtils
                        .unescapeHtml4(AllData.neardeallist.get(i)
                                .getDealTitle())),

                StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(StringEscapeUtils
                        .unescapeHtml4(AllData.neardeallist.get(i)
                                .getDescription()))
                        + ":"
                        + AllData.neardeallist.get(i).getDealId()
                        + ":" + AllData.neardeallist.get(i).getDealKey(),
                AllData.neardeallist.get(i).getDealImg());

        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
```

My Custom overlay class..!

public class CustomItemizedOverlay extends
        BalloonItemizedOverlay {

```
private ArrayList<CustomOverlayItem> m_overlays = new ArrayList<CustomOverlayItem>();
private Context c;

public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView) {
    super(boundCenter(defaultMarker), mapView);
    c = mapView.getContext();
}

public void addOverlay(CustomOverlayItem overlay) {
    m_overlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

protected CustomOverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return m_overlays.get(i);
}

public int size() {
    return m_overlays.size();
}

protected boolean onBalloonTap(int i, CustomOverlayItem item) {


        String[] Address = m_overlays.get(i).getSnippet().split(":");

        Intent intent = new Intent(c, DealDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra("deal_id", Address[1]);
        intent.putExtra("deal_key", Address[2]);
        c.startActivity(intent);


    return true;
}

@Override
protected BalloonOverlayView<CustomOverlayItem> createBalloonOverlayView() {
    // use our custom balloon view with our custom overlay item type:
    return new CustomBalloonOverlayView<CustomOverlayItem>(getMapView()
            .getContext(), getBalloonBottomOffset());
}
```

}